ProVerif error : bitstring comparison and type mismatch in XOR function
I'm using ProVerif 2.05 for modeling cryptographic protocols, but I'm running into errors when performing bitwise operations with the XOR function.
The error tells me that I have a type mismatch when trying to compare a bitstring to a natural number and I get an error when trying to compare the result of an XOR operation to 0 using the = operator.
let xor_result = XOR(XOR(XOR(Kn, r2), m), XOR(Hash(UID), PRNG(m))) in
if xor_result = 0 then  
    event ToServer();

I tried using XOR operations on bitstring values and then comparing the result to 0 to trigger the event if the result is zero.
I keep getting these errors :

Error: Syntax error
Error: bitstring should be a function or a predicate.
Error: Function = expects two arguments of same type but is here given 2 arguments of types bitstring, nat.

